# How to run from Powershell a VBA macro that does a SAPLogon

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, sap-analysis-for-office

I have an Excel that uses the Analysis for Office Add-In. It has a VBA macro that, among other things, does this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Application.Run("SAPLogon", "DS_1", "100", "myuser", "mypassword")
```

When I run the macro form Excel it works, but I'm trying to automate it with Powershell, and when I try to call it form there, I get this error:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Cannot run the macro 'SAPLogon'. The macro may not be available in this 
workbook or all macros may be disabled.
```

As it tends to get disabled sometimes, I tried enabling the "Analysis" add-in first like this in the same macro:

```
For ndx = 1 To Application.COMAddIns.Count
    If Application.COMAddIns(ndx).Description = "Analysis" Then
        Application.COMAddIns(ndx).Connect = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

But it still doesn't work.
Running other macros from the same Powershel does work.
What am I missing?

Comment: Are you running Excel file from netwrok share?

Comment: Hi Kirill. I'm not sure if that's what you're asking, but the file is in my local disk.

Comment: Are you sure the other macro that you tested successfully are in the same Excel module? and have exactly the same parameters? Try different possibilities until you see it not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample of my PowerShell code in which I'm opening an Excel file, running the macro *CreateChart* and saving then closing the file again.

```
$excel = new-object -comobject excel.application
$workbook = $excel.workbooks.open("C:\Excel\Temp\File.xlsx")
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.item(1)
$excel.Run("CreateChart")
$workbook.save()
$workbook.close()
$excel.quit()
```

I'd recommend adjusting this sample according to your code and check whether your way of running the macro was wrong perhaps.

Comment: Hi Maurice. I do something similar to that in my Powershell script, and it works with other macros in my file, but not with the one that has the SAP command.

Comment: Then I think you'd be better off asking this question on [SAP forums](https://www.sap.com/community.html).

Comment: You are probably right, I'll try that, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: I don't understand why it should be a SAP problem if the error says "cannot run the macro".